# Nodejs async.eachSeries

Tags: node.js

I asked few questions about this few months ago and recently I got back to that script. I figured out some thing and a friend helped with the script but now I have another problem.

This is my script now:

```
var j = schedule.scheduleJob('*/5 * * * * *', function(){
    var steamids = [];

    con.query("SELECT * FROM counterStrikeGlobalOffensive", function (err, rows) {
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            steamids.push(rows[i].steam64ID);
        }

        //const steamIDs = ["2342342341234123", "23423412341234", "2342314123423"]; // Steam IDs to check
        eachSeries(steamids, (steamID, callback) => {
            CSGOCli.playerProfileRequest(CSGOCli.ToAccountID(steamID));    
            CSGOCli.on("playerProfile", function(profile) {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(profile, null, 2));
                        callback();
            });
        }, (err) => {
           // error thrown = set, else we're done
        });
    });
});
```

When I use constant steamIDs, it works perfectly, but when I use steamids, it gives me an error.(I will explain)...

When I do, console.log(steamids); it returns me this

```
[ '76561198152643711', '76561198213530057' ]
```

and steamIDs is

```
const steamIDs = ["2342342341234123", "23423412341234", "2342314123423"];
```

so its almost the same as constant SteamIDs but constant has " " around the numbers which shouldn't be why it isn't working but maybe I'm wrong?

Also, I have the callback() but how can I make it stop giving me an error 
Error: Callback was already called.

Ask for any other info please :)

Comment: My suggestion will be to move away from async module and use the native or Bluebird `Promises` with `Async-Await`

Comment: Yea, that's too complicated since I used node js for like 2days and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You get the `Error: Callback was already called.` because the `CSGOCli.on()` is executed multiple times. So it calls the callback once, and later the event fires again. So the callback gets called again but it should only be called once.

For a simple reproduction see this example:

```
async.eachSeries([1, 2, 3], (data, callback) => {
  console.log("Data:", data);
  for(let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    callback();
  }
},
(err) => {
  console.log("Callback: ", err);
});
```

But if you add return before the callback like this: `return callback();`, then the problem disappears because the function will return and no callbacks will be called again.

So change your code to this and see if it works:

```
CSGOCli.on("playerProfile", function(profile) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(profile, null, 2));
            return callback();
});
```

Comment: So I did what you said, it works but I still get the 
/root/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:903
        if (fn === null) throw new Error("Callback was already called.");
Error: Callback was already called.

Comment: Maybe try to add a return before the command as well: `return CSGOCli.on("playerProfile", ...`